# How can a simple ManyToOne relationship create both a join table but also a FK back to parent?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, h2

Very simple use case.Entity Pet is ManyToOne to Customer :

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Customer.class, optional = false)
    private Customer customer;
```

Customer entity itself has a reference to Pet

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Pet.class)
        private List<Pet> pets;
```

.

This is the ERD generated:
[image]

The DDL generated is :

```
 create table customer (
       id bigint generated by default as identity,
        name varchar(255),
        notes varchar(255),
        phone_number varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    )

    create table customer_pets (
       customer_id bigint not null,
        pets_id bigint not null
    )


    create table pet (
       id bigint generated by default as identity,
        birth_date date,
        name varchar(255),
        notes varchar(255),
        type integer,
        customer_id bigint not null,
        primary key (id)
    )

  alter table customer_pets 
       add constraint UK_e3o1kteg0lcbv0x7ootmqr9be unique (pets_id)

    alter table customer_pets 
       add constraint FKgg2of4dlj1tcnp4we00jnym8n 
       foreign key (pets_id) 
       references pet

    alter table customer_pets 
       add constraint FK3vxa5mji0399s17amtnv2f2qj 
       foreign key (customer_id) 
       references customer

alter table pet 
       add constraint FKt742r2fu4c3i9sn6a8kv0k746 
       foreign key (customer_id) 
       references customer
```

The full definition of the entities is :

```
@Entity
@Table
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Pet implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private PetType type;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Customer.class, optional = false)
    private Customer customer;

    private LocalDate birthDate;

    private String notes;
}


@Entity
@Table
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    private String phoneNumber;

    private String notes;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Pet.class)
    private List<Pet> pets;

    public void insertPet(Pet pet) {
        pets.add(pet);
    }
}
```

How come Hibernate creates **both** a join table, *customer_pets*, but also keeps a FK back from *Pet to Customer*? Shouldn't be **one or the other** ?

I've also used JoinColumn, but still the same!

Comment: If you could provide full definition of your two entities, this could help people spot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your mapping is wrong. You have to tell Hibernate which to-one association maps this one-to-many association, i.e. use:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
private List<Pet> pets;
```